# Best way to handle invoicing and payments

Tags: architecture

I'm looking for just some suggestions here. I have to build an invoicing system where people will add in notes and time, and it will create an invoice at the end of the month.

I have the adding piece done, as well as creating the invoice and what not. My next step is to integrate payments into this. Here's some scenarios.

Customer A get's an invoice for Jan and doesn't pay it, more stuff get's added in Feb, so the next invoice would show all of their Feb charges, plus the carry over balance from Jan.

Customer B pays $500 in advance, they have charges in Jan for 200, so the invoice would show that they had a credit of 500, charges of 200, and a net balance of 300.

These will only go out once a month, so I'm pondering as how to go about it. I already have the invoice items adding done. I.e. people can go in and add entries and it totals everything. There is a download button that exports it to a pdf that creates the invoice. Right now, it just shows a total at the bottom.

I was thinking of adding a payments page, and then storing each payment as it's own record, but should I also create like an account balance page? Also, for historical purposes, should I create a new entry in that balance table every time the invoices go out (once a month) that could be triggered by a button?

If anyone has any ideas, tips, or a better way, I'm all ears.

Comment: IMHO this question is off-topic (although it is a good one). In fact it does not relate to coding in any way as it is all about business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't write your own accounting software.

There are lots of open-source alternatives, and if you want to redistribute it, there are BSD-licensed products like [GNU Cash](http://www.gnucash.org/).

I promise you that developing an accounting system from scratch is a VERY big project, one which you will need to have some serious accounting training or consulting before embarking on.

Comment: Well it's somewhat of a unique situation, and we really need to build just a few pieces from the ground up. Believe me, I'm all for using other stuff that's already built as I know someone out there has done it better than I will, but my situation requires what it requires.

Comment: Ok, then you should definitely read up on double-entry bookkeeping.  It will outline your best practices on writing accounting software.  The short answer is, yes, you should create a separate payments table.  You should also create a general ledger to track invoices & payments.  Finally, you should follow accounting practices to "close out" invoice & revenue tables to your account summary tables on a regular basis.  This will help you do trial balances to keep everything balanced.